# How can I get an animation to run when input submit is clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have a form which I want each time I validate if the information is empty, to run an animation of a library that imports from CSS called Animate.CSS, so I have created a function to validate each input, so if one is empty, it runs an "shake" animation of the library I mentioned. At the same time, the class has to be added, but removed at the end  in case the user does not write in the input again, the animation runs.

This is my form:

```
            <form action="" id="form">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                id="name"
                minlength="3"
                required
              />
              <br />
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Emai" id="email" required />
              <br />
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Subject"
                id="subject"
                minlength="3"
                required
              />
              <br />
              <label for="message">Message</label>
              <textarea
                name="message"
                id="message"
                minlength="5"
                placeholder="Message"
                required
                style="resize: none; height: 200px"
              ></textarea>
              <br />
              <button type="submit" class="paper-btn" id="submit">
                Send message
              </button>
            </form>
```

And Javascript:

```
(function () {
  var form = document.getElementById("form"),
    name = form.name,
    email = form.email,
    subject = form.subject;
  message = form.message;

  function validateName(e) {
    if (name.value == "" || name.value == null) {
      form.classList.add("animate__animated");
      name.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
  function validateEmail(e) {
    if (email.value == "" || email.value == null) {
      email.classList.add("animate__animated");
      email.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    }
  }

  function validateSubject(e) {
    if (subject.value == "" || subject.value == null) {
      subject.classList.add("animate__animated");
      subject.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    }
  }

  function validateMessage(e) {
    if (subject.value == "" || subject.value == null) {
      message.classList.add("animate__animated");
      message.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
      e.preventDefaul();
    }
  }

  function validateForm(e) {
    validateName(e);
    validateEmail(e);
    validateSubject(e);
    validateMessage(e);
  }
  form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
});
```

This code works, apparently, but it happens when I click on refresh and not when I click on submit:

```
var form = document.getElementById("name");
if (form.value == "" || form.value == null) {
  form.classList.add("animate__animated");
  form.classList.add("animate__shakeX");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot going on in there so I simplified some stuff to make a little more sense to me but you should go through your code and check for errors as there are quite a few there. I have made a little demo of what I assume you wanted the form to do.

```js
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  validateName();
  validateEmail();
  validateSubject();
  validateMessage();
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(removeAnimations, "2000");
})

function validateName() {
  const name = document.getElementById("name");
  if(name.value.length < 3) {
    name.classList.add("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  } else {
    name.classList.remove("animate__red");
  }
}

function validateEmail() {
  const ele = document.getElementById("email");
  if(ele.value.length < 1) {
    ele.classList.add("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  } else {
    ele.classList.remove("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  }
}

function validateSubject() {
  const ele = document.getElementById("subject");
  if(ele.value.length < 3) {
    ele.classList.add("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  } else {
    ele.classList.remove("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  }
}

function validateMessage() {
  const ele = document.getElementById("message");
  if(ele.value.length < 3) {
    ele.classList.add("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  } else {
    ele.classList.remove("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  }
}

function removeAnimations() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".animate__red")
    .forEach((ele) => {
    ele.classList.remove("animate__red", "animate__animated");
  });
}
```

```css
.animate__red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" minlength="3"  />
  <br />
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"  />
  <br />
  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" minlength="3"  />
  <br />
  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" minlength="5" placeholder="Message"  style="resize: none; height: 200px"></textarea>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="paper-btn" id="submit">
    Send message
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I just replaced the animation of "animate__red" with mine and it worked.Can you tell me what my mistakes were? Please

Comment: Just one more question, why my form doesn't send anything? With the old code it could be possible, but now the submit button doesn't do anything

Comment: That would be the `e.preventDefault()`, it stops the event from doing what it would originally do. Most mistakes were just spelling and other syntactical errors like your placeholder for email and using `e.preventDefaul` missing the "t" at the end